# AJAX to send HTML request to PHP function

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I've got a small webpage I'm writing that will feature a couple of tables of data from SQL.  I need to have a drop down HTML box that will send a value to the listening AJAX script which will then send that value on to the PHP function (to retrieve the appropriate table from SQL).

I believe I have everything set up correctly, but when I select an option from the dropdown box, nothing happens.  What am I missing here?  Thanks for any and all suggestions!

**menu.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lan="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Menu').change(function(){
                //Selected value
                var tableoptions = $(this).val();

                //Ajax for calling php function
                $.post('sqlQuery.php', { tableselected: tableoptions }, function(data){
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="Menu">
        <option value='' disabled selected>Select Device</option>
        <option value='capacitors'>Capacitors</option>
        <option value='inductors'>Inductors</option>
        <option value='resistors'>Resistors</option>
        <option value='miscellaneous'>Miscellaneous</option>
     </select>
</body>
```

**sqlQuery.php**

```
<?php
function processUserInp($table) {
      //This is where $table is passed as the table name
      //for the SQL query
}
if ($_POST['tableselected']){
    //call the function!
    processUserInp($_POST['tableselected']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to console log the response? Do you have any errors? more info is required in order to help you

Comment: `sqlQeury.php` appears to be mis-spelled. Also, have you been watching your console and network tabs in your developer tools to see if the request is fired and what the response is. I mean, your JS code runs the `$.post`, but the callback receives `data` (the response) and then does nothing with it, so it's not clear what you really thought was going to happen visually? Just because nothing happens in the web page though, doesn't mean that literally nothing is happening! You need to debug.

Comment: This is the error in the log: `HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost/sqlQeury.php`

Comment: Well, like I said, it looks like a typo - surely it should be `sqlQuery.php`? A 404 would be explained by a typo, if there's no such script with the mis-spelled name.

Comment: Right, thanks for the catch, hadn't noticed that.  I'm pretty new to using HTML in conjunction with ajax.  What is the purpose of function(data) exactly?  (I found this portion of code, didn't write it myself)

Comment: You should probably take an AJAX/jQuery tutorial instead of copy/pasting code you don't understand....what if it turned out to do something undesirable?? The purpose of that callback is to allow you to process the response from the server. So in your case `data` will contain anything which your sqlQuery.php script outputs by means of an `echo` statement. Then you can choose to process the data in some way, or display it on screen inside a HTML element, or whatever it was you intended to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, sorry for being difficult.  I'm just trying to finish a project that has a deadline in a few weeks that needed a quick fix, in this case AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, as someone noticed in the comment, you have misspelled the PHP script file name. Make sure it's the same as the actual file name.

Secondly, your current code is not doing anything once it receives the data from the backend PHP script. Look at this part of your code:

```
$.post('sqlQuery.php', { tableselected: tableoptions }, function(data){               
});
```

This should contain the logic of what you want to do once you get back some data from the server. For example:

```
$.post('sqlQuery.php', { tableselected: tableoptions }, function(data){
    console.log(data); // or print data somewhere on the DOM            
});
```

Your frontend code is working fine (I checked it), assuming that your backend code also works fine (you did not share the entire code so could not test it), then all you need to do is to handle the response that you get back from the PHP script in the backend.

**UPDATE:** To reply to your comment, you can do the following:

First, add an empty  element in your HTML code like so:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

and then, update your jQuery method to insert the returned HTML in this div instead of simply logging it on the console using console.log. Here is how it would look like:

```
$.post('sqlQuery.php', { tableselected: tableoptions }, function(data){
    $("#output").html(data); // or print data somewhere on the DOM            
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My backend code actually formats and fills an html table with the data from the SQL tables.  So the `data` that is retrieved with AJAX is a lot of `<table><th><tr … values, values, values, ></th></table>`.  Is there a clean way to get all of this to correctly display as a table in the DOM as opposed to just as a large string in a console log?

Comment: Np @Jonny1998 - yes, there is an easy way. I will update my answer to add a code sample.

Comment: @Jonny1998 please check the update in my answer, hope that sorts it out for you. As an additional side note, consider reading up on things like SQL injection and web security in general. Goodluck!

Comment: Very helpful!  I will look into those things as well.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**menu.html**

```
<select onchange="$.get('sqlQuery.php?device='+this.value,function(data){$('#devicedetail').innerHTML=data;});">
<option value='1'>Capacitors</option>
<option value='2'>Inductors</option>
<option value='3'>Resistors</option>
<option value='4'>Miscellaneous</option>
</select>
<div id=devicedetail></div>
```

**sqlQuery.php**

```
<?php
echo "here are details of device $_GET[device]...";
?>
```

the event onchange on the select tag... make a request... send the id of a device in url (sqlQuery.php?device=3 (example))

the page sqlQuery.php should search for data about the device on a database...

when sqlQuery.php send de data back to menu.html... the ajax show details in div devicedetails